# How can I successfully include jquery in karma with requireJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, karma-jasmine

I am attempting to write karma tests, some of which require jquery. I am using requirejs.

Here is the relevant part of my karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({

        // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
        basePath: '',


        // frameworks to use
        // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
        frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],


        // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
        files: [
            'spec/test-main.js',
            //tests
            {pattern: 'spec/**/*.js', included: true},
            //application files
            {pattern: 'apps/**/*.js', included: false},
            //jquery
            {pattern: 'bower_components/jquery/src/*.js', included: false, served: true}
        ],
        ...
```

And my test-main.js:

```
var tests = [];
for (var file in window.__karma__.files) {
    if (window.__karma__.files.hasOwnProperty(file)) {
        if (/spec\.js$/.test(file)) {
            tests.push(file);
        }
    }
}

requirejs.config({
    // Karma serves files from '/base'
    baseUrl: '/base',

    paths: {
        'jquery': 'bower_components/jquery/src/jquery'
    },

    map: {
        '*': {
            'jquery' : 'jquery'
        }
    },

    shim: {
        'jquery': {
            exports: '$'
        }
    },

    // ask Require.js to load these files (all our tests)
    deps: tests,

    // start test run, once Require.js is done
    callback: window.__karma__.start
});
```

As is, I get:

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined

for every spot I try to use jQuery. I also get, in the browser:

> There is no timestamp for /base/(myPath).js!

Where (myPath) is the path to my file under test, which I find odd because that file resides under the path specified for application files in `karma.conf.js`.

1. If I take out the jquery tests, the other tests will execute and succeed.
2. If I change the "included" property to true in my `karma.conf` file list for jquery, I will get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define()

3. If I attempt to add 'jquery' to the frameworks array in `karma.conf`, karma won't even start.
4. If I try to wrap my tests with some require shenanigans like `require(['jquery'], function($) {` the tests will not run and I'll get

> Executed 0 of 0 ERROR.

5. I've also tried using `define(function (require) {var $ = require('jquery');` which just gives me another

> Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define()

6. `var $ = require('jquery')` results in:

> Uncaught Error: Module name "jquery" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

Anyway, I've done quite a bit of searching around for similar problems and any solutions and I haven't been able to get this to work. Ideally, jquery would just be available for all my tests via karma, but even being able to require it manually in my test itself would be fine at this point. Also, not getting the `no timestamp` error would be nice. Any advice?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

After a lot of trial and error, I think I've made some progress towards the goal, though I'm not quite there yet.

karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({

        // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
        basePath: '',


        // frameworks to use
        // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
        frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],


        // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
        files: [
          //jquery
          {pattern: 'node_modules/jquery/src/*.js', included: false},
          {pattern: 'node_modules/jquery/src/**/*.js', included: false},
          //application files
          {pattern: 'apps/**/*.js', included: false},
          //tests
          {pattern: 'spec/**/*.js', included: true},
          'test-main.js'
        ],
        ...
```

Changed the order of the files here and added sub-directories of jquery. The real change came below in test-main.js:

```
var tests = [];
for (var file in window.__karma__.files) {
    if (window.__karma__.files.hasOwnProperty(file)) {
        if (/spec\.js$/.test(file)) {
          tests.push(file);
        }
    }
}

requirejs.config({
    // Karma serves files from '/base'
    baseUrl: '/base',

    paths: {
        'jquery': 'node_modules/jquery/src/jquery'
    },

    map: {
        '*': {
            'jquery' : '/base/node_modules/jquery/src/jquery.js'
        }
    },

    shim: {

    },

    // ask Require.js to load these files (all our tests)
    deps: tests,

    // start test run, once Require.js is done
    callback: window.__karma__.start
});
```

Apparently when I previously had jquery in the shim object, that was wrong, and it was hiding a bunch of 404s. I am now getting a 404 for all the jquery dependencies, because jquery depends them via relative paths - requireJS does not append .js onto files required via relative paths.

So now I just need a way to tell requirejs to append the .js to the dependencies (other than brute-forcing it into every jquery file), and then hopefully this will be resolved. Anyone know how to do that?

**EDIT 2:** I skipped the middleman and just downloaded jquery-2.2.2.min rather than bother with a module version.

There were other hurdles I needed to clear as well: the order of the files as you include them in karma.conf.js matters, and in test-main.js, apparently only files with spec in the file name were being included as tests. I also needed to set all those 'included' properties to false.

Finally, in my case, my module that I am testing is defined using a string that's slightly different from the path karma is finding it by. Example:

```
//addition-functions.js
define('myModules/calculator/addition-functions', [], function () {
```

and in the test file:

```
//test-file.js
define(['jquery', 'myModules/calculator/addition-functions'], function($, addFunctions) {
```

If I did only this, I would 404 on my module, because it expects it to be within the apps folder. However, I cannot add apps to the path directly. I must use the paths variable in my test-main.js, like so:

```
requirejs.config({
// Karma serves files from '/base'
baseUrl: '/base',

paths: {
    'jquery': 'lib/jquery-2.2.2.min',
    'myModules/calculator/addition-functions' : 'apps/myModules/calculator/addition-functions'
},
...
```

This got things working. Will mark this as solved.

Comment: So is this a question, or an answer???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add jquery to jasmine/angularjs unittests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073570/how-to-add-jquery-to-jasmine-angularjs-unittests)