# ReferenceError: $ is not defined - Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, unit-testing, jasmine

I never used Jasmine before but I'm required for this little project that I'm working on. Can't quite figure it out, any help would be appreciated. I have looked at various tutorials and googeled the problem but being new to this does not help.

JS source file

```
> $(document).ready(function(){
>    
> 
> $.ajax({ type: 'GET', dataType: "json", url: "db.php/realmadrids", 
> success: showResponse,  error: showError });
> 
> 
> 
>  
> 
> 
> console.debug("error");   function showResponse(responseData){
> 
>   //$("#get1").click(function getPlayers(responseData) { 
>   console.log('Image is clicked');    console.log(responseData);
>     $.each(responseData.realmadrid, function(index, realmadrid){
>       console.log(' is ');
>         $("#playercontentRealMadrid").append("</br><strong> Full Name: </strong>" +realmadrid.PlayerName+ " "+realmadrid.PlayerLastName+"
> </br> <strong>Player Position: </strong>" +realmadrid.PlayerPosition+"
> </br><strong>Player Age: </strong>" +realmadrid.Age+"
> </br><strong>Player Height: </strong>" +realmadrid.Height+"
> </br><strong>Player Weight: </strong>" +realmadrid.Weight+"
> </br><strong>Team Name: </strong>" +realmadrid.TeamName+"</br>");
>     
>         console.log('Data should output'); // });   });
> 
> console.log(responseData);
>     }
>     console.debug("hello");
> 
> function showError(){ alert("Sorry, but something went wrong. Fix
> it!!!!") }
> 
> });
```

Here is my test code:

> ```
> //Test Suite
> describe("Spy on my own AJAX call", function(){
>     
>     it("should make AJAX request with successful setting", function() {
>     
>         spyOn($, "ajax");
>         
>         expect($.ajax).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
>             url:'db.php/realmadrids',
>             type:'GET',
>             dataType: "json",
>             sucess: showResponse,
>             error: showError
>         });
>     
>     });
>    
> });
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include jQuery.

In this case `$` is actually a function (from the jQuery library) and because jQuery hasn't been loaded your getting the error that this function is not defined.

Include jQuery in the same manner that you are including the Jasmine library. One approach would be to use the CDN:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 10):

I have the same issue in my Angular 7 project.
The below steps solved the issue.

add below code on top of the spec.ts file

```
    declare var $: any;
```

A Karma plugin - adapter for jQuery framework.

```
    npm install karma-jquery --save-dev
```

Add the '**karma-jquery**' in 'plugins' array in the karma.conf.js file

```
    module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({

    plugins: ['karma-jquery']
```

Add version of the jquery in frameworks array in the same file.

```
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular','jquery-3.2.1']
```

Comment: This is appropriate and superior to the accepted answer for Angular testing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this approach, it's simple!

Into file karma.conf.ts I've put the path of jquery.

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      './node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
      //..rest files      
    ],

    //rest karma options
  });
};
```

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/19073586/231391

Answer (score 0):

For me, adding the script to `karma.conf.ts` file didn't make any difference, but updating the `angular.json` file in the "test" section, to include the jQuery script, made it work:

```
"test": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
  "options": {
    "main": "src/test.ts",
    "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
    "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
    "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
    "styles": ["src/styles.scss"],
    "scripts": [
      "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"  // <-- here
    ],
    "assets": ["src/assets"],
    "codeCoverage": true
  }
},
```

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/55261096/1562369