# ReferenceError: $ is not defined in Jasmine specs

Tags: angular6

My `component` has a method `showDialog` which uses `JQuery`'s `$` to create a ` modal.

```
declare var $: any;
dialogShow(message:string, context:DialogContext){

    this.dialogContext = context;
    this.dialogMessage = message;

    $(this.dialogRef.nativeElement).modal('show');
    }
```

I am trying to create a `spec` for the component but I am getting error

`ReferenceError: $ is not defined`
        `at DialogBoxComponent../src/app/dialog-box/dialog-box.component.ts.DialogBoxComponent.dialogShow src/app/dialog-box/dialog-box.component.ts:82:5)`

The `spec` is

```
  declare var $: any;
describe('dialogShow ',()=>{
    it('should show dialog box with correct message',()=>{
     let dialogBox = new DialogBoxComponent();
     let dialogMessage="some message";
     dialogBox.dialogID="some id";
     let dialogContext= new DialogContext("some context id","some context");
     dialogBox.dialogShow(dialogMessage,dialogContext);
     expect(dialogBox.dialogMessage).toEqual(dialogMessage);
     expect(dialogBox.dialogContext).toEqual(dialogContext);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add jquery to jasmine/angularjs unittests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073570/how-to-add-jquery-to-jasmine-angularjs-unittests)

Comment: I changed `karma.conf.js` and added line `files:['..\\public\\javascripts\\common\\vendor\\jquery\\jquery-3.3.1.js'],` in it

Comment: I also added `Bootstrap.js` in similar way for `modal` function